# What is the fastest way to perform a discrete Fourier transform of an even extension?

Tags: python, scipy, fft

I have a discretized representation of a particle trajectory `q(t), t=0..T`, i.e. I have `q_n, n=0..N`. I want to have a spectral representation for computing derivatives accurately, but the signal is not periodic. Given the application an even expansion seems the best way to go, but how do I implement this efficiently (in Python/scipy)? It seems to me there must exist some way of doing this *without* first constructing the even-expanded array with `2N` entries. Also, doing so would result in a `2N` cosines after a `dct`, but half of them will be zero.